# Big Query insertAll() only inserting last row

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery

I'm trying to insert rows into a table in Big Query using the Node package called [bigquery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bigquery) which acts as a wrapper around the BQ API itself and uses the [insertAll() API call.](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tabledata/insertAll)

However, when loading an array of more than one item, only the last item in the array is actually inserted into the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, actually asking the question has allowed me to solve it myself.  I was posting rows with identical insertIds, causing all but one to be ignored.